# Remove characters with javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have various img src's like this:
http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/img-80x93.jpg
http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/image-80x110.jpg
...

I want to change them to:
http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/img.jpg
http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/image.jpg
...

Basically what I need is to remove from -80x until .jpg

I tried to remove "-80x" + all the numbers after that:

.replace('-80x'/\d+/g,''));

but didn't work... and others replaces but with no result.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with jQuery - it's plain-old JavaScript.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I've edited it, it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need the "-80x" to be inside your regex, like:

```
someString.replace(/-80x\d+/g,"")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var source="http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/img-80x93.jpg";    
var url=source.split('-80x')[0]+".jpg";
```

it will give you "http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/img.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

Edited:
This works.

```
.replace(/\-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.jpg/g, '.jpg');
```